# How to center-align one flex item and right-align another using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am totally new to Flexbox and wanted to align buttons, but I could not see how to handle the common case with a center-aligned button and a right-aligned button on the same row using only Flexbox.

However, I found a way that used an invisible left-aligned item of the same length as the right-aligned item and the flex `justify-content` with `space-between` to make the middle item centered on the row.

Is there a more direct way with Flexbox?

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.iteminvisible {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.itemcenter {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.itemright {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="iteminvisible">Other</div>
  <div class="itemcenter">One</div>
  <div class="itemright">Other</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 66):

Using `justify-content: space-between` with an invisible flex item, as described in your question, is a good way to achieve the layout you want. Just note that the middle item can only be centered if both left and right items are equal length ([see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7an37m20/2/)).

Another solution you may want to consider involves [`auto` margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) and [absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items). Two benefits of this method are no need for extra mark-up and true centering can be achieved regardless item sizes. One drawback is that the centered item is removed from the [document flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow) (which may or may not matter to you).

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /* adjustment */
  position: relative;
  /* new */
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.itemcenter {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  /* new */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.itemright {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  /* new */
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="itemcenter">One</div>
  <div class="itemright">Other</div>
</div>
```

More details here: [**Methods for Aligning Flex Items along the Main Axis**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) (see boxes #62-78).

Comment: This doesn't center.. It depends on the width of the elements that are to the left/right. If they are the same this works. If not this don't work.

Comment: I can't believe there's not a better solution to this. I tried using `justify-content: center` and then `align-self` on the right element, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; //this will allow flex-end to move item to the right
  align-items: center;
}
.right-item {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: But this puts the right-item below the middle one, no?

Comment: this puts the items in separate rows

Comment: that's not the expected behaviour
see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jLw437s2/