# How to use flexbox to have a centered item and another item on the left (on a bootom nav bar)?

Tags: html, css

Im struggling to make my first item (number 1, as seen in the picture) stay in the middle of the bottom nav bar.
Im using flexbox, so float: right doesnt work for my second item (number 2).

This is the picture:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<div className='Footer'>
      <div className='Footer-ContainerTeclado'>
            
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faVials} style={{color:"#0D69AF", margin:'15px'}}/>
            <h2>{NombreLab}</h2>
          

            <div className="custom-itemFooterTeclado">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPowerOff}/>
            </div>

      </div>
   </div>
```

And this is my css:

```
    .Footer{
    margin-top:1rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:10vh;
}
    .Footer-ContainerTeclado{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.Footer-ContainerTeclado h2{
    color: black;
    order:2,
}

.custom-itemFooterTeclado{
    color:#E3655B;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: I believe this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444666/how-to-center-align-one-flex-item-and-right-align-another-using-flexbox) and [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/right-or-left-align-one-flex-item-while-keeping-the-others-centered).  That second one has a highly voted answer with many approaches you might take-- I might personally favor grid, as it seems like potentially a better fit for your needs here.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @AlexanderNied thank you! I solved it using one of those answers!

Comment: Glad this worked! Thanks for adding your solution as an answer to the post for future visitors.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with an answer from the other post:

```
 <ul>
  <li class="a">A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li class="d">D</li>
</ul>

ul {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}


.a,.d {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className='Footer'>
      <div className='Footer-ContainerTeclado'>
            <div class="centered-block">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faVials} style={{color:"#0D69AF", margin:'15px'}}/>
                <h2>{NombreLab}</h2>  
            </div>
            <div className="custom-itemFooterTeclado">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPowerOff}/>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

```
.Footer-ContainerTeclado{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I believe the asker wants the `<h2/>` centered and the "power off" button right aligned.