# Align active button centre in a Flex div

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML code which contains three button inside a flex div as bellow;
When a user click on any of the buttons, that button will have the `active` class.

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexbox {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h4>HELLO</h4>
  <div class="flexbox">
    <button class="active">ONE</button>
    <button>TWO</button>
    <button>THREE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need to achieve here is the button contain the `active` class should always be centre aligned in side the `flex box`.

According to the above, the button ONE has the `active` class and it should be centre aligned in side the `flexbox` and other two buttons should go right.

You can get the idea from the image below

[image]

NOTE: Preferred to solve this with use CSS only.

Comment: and what about the other 2 buttons, Do you want active button in center and other 2 button on left??

Comment: The order of the buttons has to be fixed.

Comment: Possible answers: 
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444666/how-to-center-align-one-flex-item-and-right-align-another-using-flexbox
2. Grids: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-one-and-right-left-align-other-flexbox-element

Comment: always 3 buttons or it can be any number?

Comment: It can be any number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only 3 buttons here is an idea using CSS grid:

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center; /* center the grid */
}

.flexbox {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); /* 5 columns */
  justify-content: center; /* center the columns */
  gap: 5px;
}

.active {
  grid-column: 3; /* active always on the middle */
}
/* we need a "hacky" code for the second case */
.active:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area:1/1;
  transform:translate(calc(200% + 10px)); /* 10px = 2xgap */
}
.active:nth-child(2) ~ :last-child {
  grid-column:4;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h4>HELLO</h4>
  <div class="flexbox">
    <button class="active">ONE</button>
    <button>TWO</button>
    <button>THREE</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <h4>HELLO</h4>
  <div class="flexbox">
    <button >ONE</button>
    <button class="active">TWO</button>
    <button>THREE</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <h4>HELLO</h4>
  <div class="flexbox">
    <button >ONE</button>
    <button >TWO</button>
    <button class="active">THREE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```